# Erro ao construir projeto com bilbioteca Commons-Email-1.4

Tags: java, netbeans, compilação, biblioteca, ant

No meu projeto precisei adicionar a opção de envio de e-mails adicionei a biblioteca `commons-email-1.4` escrevi todo o código e testei. Até o momento tudo perfeito porém ao limpar e construir o arquivo .jar da aplicação, eis que surge o erro.

```
ant -f C:\\Users\\Clayton\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Agil307 - Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild clean jar
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: C:\Users\Clayton\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Agil307\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory C:\Users\Clayton\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Agil307\build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: C:\Users\Clayton\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Agil307\build
Updating property file: C:\Users\Clayton\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Agil307\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: C:\Users\Clayton\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Agil307\build\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\Clayton\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Agil307\build\classes\META-INF
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\Clayton\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Agil307\build\classes\META-INF
Created dir: C:\Users\Clayton\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Agil307\build\empty
Created dir: C:\Users\Clayton\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Agil307\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 401 source files to C:\Users\Clayton\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Agil307\build\classes
C:\Users\Clayton\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Agil307\nbproject\build-impl.xml:929: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Clayton\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Agil307\nbproject\build-impl.xml:269: Error running C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\javac.exe compiler
FALHA NA CONSTRUÇÃO (tempo total: 49 segundos)
```

Linhas referente aos erros acima no arquivo `build-impl.xml`

```
 928<target depends="init,deps-jar,-pre-pre-compile,-pre-compile, -copy-persistence-xml,-compile-depend" if="have.sources" name="-do-compile">
 929   <j2seproject3:javac gensrcdir="${build.generated.sources.dir}"/>
 930      <copy todir="${build.classes.dir}">
 931         <fileset dir="${src.dir}" excludes="${build.classes.excludes},${excludes}" includes="${includes}"/>
 932      </copy>
 933</target>
```

---

```
  269<javac debug="@{debug}" deprecation="${javac.deprecation}" destdir="@{destdir}" encoding="${source.encoding}" excludes="@{excludes}" fork="${javac.fork}" includeantruntime="false" includes="@{includes}" source="${javac.source}" sourcepath="@{sourcepath}" srcdir="@{srcdir}" target="${javac.target}" tempdir="${java.io.tmpdir}">
  270           <src>
  271               <dirset dir="@{gensrcdir}" erroronmissingdir="false">
  272                   <include name="*"/>
  273               </dirset>
  274           </src>
```

Se eu remover a biblioteca `commons-email-1.4` e remover o código do projeto ele constrói sem problemas.

Não sei o que posso fazer para solucionar o problema.

Só para registro estou usando JDK 8.

Comment: Temos pouca informação para trabalhar. _"O erro seguinte aconteceu ao executar esta linha:"_ e não fala qual linha. Será a linha 269 de build-impl.xml? Ou outra linha? Seria interessante postar o trecho de build-impl.xml informando qual linha é a 269 (e a 929 também, que são as informações que temos).

Comment: Vou complementar a questão com as linhas do building.

Comment: O netbeans não mostra qual é o erro que o compilador acusa?

Comment: Quantas e quais bibliotecas você tem no projeto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de alguns dias testando esta situação consegui uma solução, eu faço utilização de varias bibliotecas e algumas estavam adicionadas mas não estavam em uso, dai no caso fiz uma varredura nas bibliotecas usadas e removi algumas delas e depois tentei realizar o processo de limpeza e construção, e simplesmente funcionou agora não sei se o projeto ou o compilador aceita um numero máximo de bibliotecas e se existia algum conflito de algumas bibliotecas, aparente as bibliotecas removidas não tinha relação alguma com as ultimas adicionadas.